# Shared encrypted file but using different key to decrypt

Tags: security, encryption, public-key-encryption

I just curious, if there any encryption algorithm that can support this scenario.

A plain text file (T) was shared among two parties, this file was encrypted (let say symmetric AES) to become encrypted file (E). The Encrypted file will be stored in the server, and after encryption takes place, additional party can be added at any time.

When first party wants to get the T file, he/she passes P1K to decrypt E file
when second party wants to get the T file, he/she passed P2K to decrypt E file.

Any idea how to achieve this using pure encryption algorithm only (without using database to store intermediary key) ?

Comment: You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605139/is-it-possible-to-have-encryption-with-multiple-private-keys-php and perhaps explain why this won't help you.  The first answer may be the answer to your question.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm aware about the symmetric key concept. My question is there any "advance" algorithm that can achieve this requirement?

Comment: What key is used to encrypt (T) to become (E)? Are you saying that the key used for decryption changes every time the file is decrypted?

Comment: I don't see the purpose of such an algorithm, as this can be done with PK already, and designing an algorithm that can have more than one key to decrypt would be a weak algorithm since there could be new attacks on the message, to find unknown keys that can decrypt it, or to find a pattern in the two keys that you found can decrypt it.

Answer (score 1):

If the sender already has the public key component for the intended recipients of the secret message than this can be done with GnuPG using paired key encrpytion.

The sender needs to encrypt the data to the public key of the intended recipients (maybe the senders own key as well) and only those people will be able to use their private key to decrypt the secret message.

Not sure if the requirement to preawareness of or access to the receivers public keys is an issue or disqualifies the answer as a type of database of info that the sender must have.

All users get to keep their private bits to themselves though as opposed to if they all had to have shared the same password, in this case no user has access to the private key any of their contacts.

http://www.gnupg.org/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the tell that the document was stored in the server not transmitted.

Comment: "but that is the question how can I encrypt a single file using different keys for different person?" can be done with assymetric encryption (GnuPG) - magical stuff, let me find a direct link...

Comment: GnuPG The --recipient option is used once for each recipient and takes an extra argument specifying the public key to which the document should be encrypted. The encrypted document can only be decrypted by someone with a private key that complements one of the recipients' public keys. In particular, you cannot decrypt a document encrypted by you unless you included your own public key in the recipient list.

-- File doesn't need to be sent/crypted separetely, can sit on server each access by own secret key.

http://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual.html#AEN111

Answer (score 1):

The plain text (T) can be encrypted with a secret key (Ks) using a symmetric cipher like AES.

Ks is encrypted with as many public keys that is allowed to know the symmetric cipher and added as part of the encrypted message packet.

Decryption just means iterating through the list of encrypted Ks against the private key of a user.

Answer (score 0):

Who passes what key to whom? (Also, traditionally P for plaintext and C for ciphertext.)

And there's an easy answer (unless I'm misunderstanding you, which is an obvious possibility since your question isn't very clear): Give each recipient "half" of the key in the first place, and the other half when you want them to be able to decrypt the message.

How do you split a key in half? A decent way is to XOR it with a nonce: give person 1 K⊕N1 and person 2 K⊕N2. When you want them to decrypt the message, give them N1 or N2 respectively.

Another easy answer is to just give each person the key encrypted with the recipient's public key when you want them to decrypt the message.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but that is the question how can I encrypt a single file using different keys for different person? As far as I know, this cannot be achieve both by symmetric and asymmetric encryption algorithm.

Comment: What, precisely, do you mean by "different keys for different person"?

Comment: as you said person1 will use key1 and person2 will have key2 to decrypt the encrypted content.

Comment: He wants to encrypt a message, and have two different keys be able to decrypt it, so user A and user B have different keys, but can decrypt the message.

Comment: Encrypt it with a message key, encrypt the message key separately with key A and key B. This is (very) loosely what DVDs/etc use to allow keys to be revoked.